# .dwg file upload and view in js/html/angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

Need to upload the .dwg format images and able to preview /view in a page which created using js/HTML/angularjs or Angular 2+?.
tried to implement CAD viewer js library but there is not much documentation available for that. So anyone implemented this or any idea how to view .dwg files dynamically in js/HTML/Angular?

Have tried CAD viewer library and try to embed the image with  in page using HTML but no result.
Even have tried Autodesk viewer but there is no proper documentation regarding how to upload and render it.

1.http://cadviewerjs.com/cv-js_api/index_cvjs_24_viewing.html

2.https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-offline.sample

3.http://cadviewerjs.com/cv-js_api/index_cvjs_24_viewing.html

these above links which I have tried.

Should able to upload .dwg format image and able to view it(irrespective of size, it has a size around 300MB sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

The demo shows that the image is rendered to a svg image. Try inspect in chrome dev or similar. All you now has to do is either to grab the svg and store it in the DB or use some kind of svg to png script to store a png in the DB. Based on the fact that they do not show their pricing information or any kind of store you can be sure it will have 4 digits before the $ sign. And by that price i am sure they will code you that simple thing. And if client has enough money to use autocad he has also the money for the pro licence :) BTW: the images of a drawing or blocks are part of the native DWG file. There is some kind of header structure which target the embedded image which autocad stores on save. Another way is to write a autocad addon which export this image on safe. [C# export block images](https://www.keanw.com/2011/11/generating-preview-images-for-all-blocks-in-an-autocad-drawing-using-net.html). Note a whole drawing is also just a "block". It has the special name "*Model_Space". And also this block has a image (as long as the user does not disabled the image generation).

And last but not least also Autocad has a javascript interface which is nothing else as a headless chrome inside autocad. Put some websock interface in such a javascript component and let autocad do the exporting thing. So you can run a autocad aside to your server headless (also possible is called autocad core console).